# TailwindCSS doesn't apply classes in Vue project

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

I have created two Vue 3 projects using Vite. One is the Design System, and the other is the main project where I will utilize the Design System. Both projects have separate repositories.

In the main project, I import the design system by referencing it in the package.json as a dependency:

`"design-system": "bitbucket:repository-url#main",`

Both projects have "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1" in devDependencies.

It is functioning correctly, as I am able to import the components I created in the Design System and use them in my main project. However, there is an unusual behavior with Tailwindcss.

For instance:

I import the `<Component A/>` from the design system, and it contains the class **"bg-primary"**. This class is not applied even though it is present in both projects. However, if I manually create a `<div class="bg-primary">`, it starts working both in the div and in the `<Component A/>` where it wasn't working.

In style.css, I imported Tailwind:

`@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`

In main.ts, I imported style.css:

```
import App from './App.vue';
import './style.css';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import router from "./router/index";

const app = createApp( App );    
   
app.use( PrimeVue ).use( router ).mount( '#app' );
```

I also created postcss.config.js in the root folder:

```
`export default {   plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},   }, };    
`
```

Tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./node_modules/primevue/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent!important',
      'FAFAFA': 'green!important',
      'primary': '#004E60',
      'primary-darker': "#14323F",
      'secondary': '#50CFC9',
      "001B21": '#001B21',
      'white': "#ffffff",
      'F8F9FA': "#F8F9FA",
      'E3E3E3': "#e3e3e3",
      '8292A6': '#8292A6',
      '007995': '#007995',
      'DCDCDC': '#DCDCDC',
      'E2E8F0': '#E2E8F0',
      'CACACA': '#cacaca',
      'danger': 'red'

    },
    fontFamily: {
      'sans': ['Poppins'],
      'serif': ['Poppins'],
      'mono': ['Poppins'],
      'display': ['Poppins'],
      'body': ['Poppins'],
    },
    fontSize: {
      esm: '0.7rem',
      sm: '0.9rem',
      base: '1rem',
      xl: '2.25rem',
      '2xl': '2.2rem',
      '3xl': '3.953rem',
      '4xl': '4.441rem',
      '5xl': '5.052rem',
    },
    screens: {
      'esm': '300px',
      'sm': '459px',
      'md': '768px',
      'lg': '1024px',
      'xl': '1280px',
      '2xl': '1536px',
    },
    extend: {
      width: {
        '100': '100px',
        '270': '270px',
      },
      height: {
        '50': '50px',
        '88': '88px',
      },
      inset: {
        '100': '100px',
        '270': '270px',
      },
      borderRadius: {
        'exl': '26px'
      },
      boxShadow: {
        '3xl': '0px 8px 8px 0px rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.20)',
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding the design system's code that contains Tailwind classes to your main project's Tailwind `content` configuration:

```js
content: [
  // …
  "./node_modules/my-design-system/path/to/components/**/*.tsx",
],
```

This tells Tailwind to scan for classes in the design system and thus will generate CSS rules for strings that match valid class name candidates.